# Identityserver4: Role based security in MVC client application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I have setup Identityserver4, API resource and MVC client application as mentioned in this [GIT repo](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts). 
I am testing this application with dot net core 2.0 framework.

- **IdentityServerWithAspIdAndEF** -> Identityserver4 setup which
  responsible to authenticate the particular user.
- **Api** -> Sample API resource
- **MvcClient** -> Server-side MVC client application.

I need to implement role-based authorization in MvcClient application as well, so I need to have claims about role in MvcClient application. I have tried implement IProfileService by refer this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066613/identity-server-4-custom-user-claims). but it didn't work.

**IdentityServerWithAspIdAndEF configuration**

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();

        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
            });
```

**MVCClient Configuration**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("api1");
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("role");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            });
```

**API Configuration**

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
            });
```

**Please suggest how can I add custom claim during authentication process on identityserver4 which can be accessible in MvcClient application?**

**Note:** Whatever claims I have added using IProfileService can be available in API but those claims are not available whitin MvcClient application. So I guess all the custom claims are included in access token, but i don't know why we are able to access this claims in MvcClient application.

Comment: Did you solve it?